# How to re-index data frame based on each partition

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following data frame created by pyspark

```
id  date         deleted
1   2019-02-07     true
1   2019-02-04     false
2   2019-02-01     true
3   2019-02-08     false
3   2019-02-06     true
```

I would like to reindex this table on daily basis from earliest date up to now (say 2019-02-09), and the earliest date is based on each id, e.g., for id 1, the earliest date is 2019-02-04, for id 3, the earliest date is 2019-02-06. And the expected result is:

```
id  date         deleted
1   2019-02-04     false
1   2019-02-05     null
1   2019-02-06     null
1   2019-02-07     true
1   2019-02-08     null
1   2019-02-09     null

2   2019-02-01     true
2   2019-02-02     null
      ...
2   2019-02-09     null

3   2019-02-06     true
3   2019-02-07     null
3   2019-02-08     false
3   2019-02-09     null
```

I knew how to do it for the earliest date based on all ids (i.e., 2019-02-01), then just construct a data frame contains all dates from 2019-02-01 to 2019-02-09 for each id (cross join), then left join the original data frame. The problem with this approach is that if there is a date say 1980-01-01, then the reindex will populate all data from 1980-01-01 to now for all ids, which does not make sense, and will affect the performance for the following ETL on this data frame.

For the the earliest date based on each partition, did not find a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your original DataFrame is called `df`, and that the `date` column is really of type `DateType`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType, ArrayType
import datetime

# create a UDF to create a range of dates from a start
# date until today
def construct_date_range(start_date):
    ndays = (datetime.datetime.today() - start_date).days
    return reversed([base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, ndays+1)])
date_range_udf = F.udf(construct_date_range, ArrayType(DateType()))

# find the first date for each id, and create a record for
# all dates since the first
id_dates = (
    df
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(F.min('date').alias('min_date'))
    .withColumn('date_arr', construct_date_range('min_date'))
    .select('id', F.explode('date_arr').alias('date'))
)

result = id_dates.join(df, on=['id','date'], how='left')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,  I think the solution is correct, just found some formatting issues. `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'`. Based on this, I made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @abeboparebop's solution, I fix some of the formatting issues and made it work as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType, ArrayType
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

SYDNEY_TZ = "Australia/Sydney"

def _utc_now():
    return datetime.utcnow()

def _current_datetime_index(timezone=SYDNEY_TZ):
    return pd.DatetimeIndex([_utc_now()]).tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert(timezone).tz_localize(None)


def current_datetime(timezone=SYDNEY_TZ):
    return _current_datetime_index(timezone).to_pydatetime()[0]

def generate_date_list(date_from, date_to=None):
    if date_to is None:
        date_to = current_datetime()
    return pd.date_range(date_from.date(), date_to.date(), freq="D").date.tolist()


def construct_date_range(start_date):
    return generate_date_list(pd.to_datetime(start_date))


date_range_udf = F.udf(construct_date_range, ArrayType(DateType()))


id_dates = (
    given_df
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(F.min('date').alias('min_date'))
    .withColumn('date_arr', date_range_udf(F.col('min_date')))
    .select('id', F.explode('date_arr').alias('date'))
)

result = id_dates.join(given_df, on=['id', 'date'], how='left')
```